# Object caching on disk in Android

Tags: android, object, caching, disk, android-internal-storage

From server I get a PictureObject. it consists of List (about 20 - 30 pictures in list), while each Picture has about 20 fiels. 
So, I need to cashe on disk each of these 20 pictures.
How should I do it. I am a beginner in networking.
If there are some useful links, tutorials, videos, please, write.

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

Use [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) it contains a variety of caching functions. The code is under Apache Licence.

Comment: Thanks, Tom, but I shouldn't use code, which is under the Licence